# How do I build RoR Joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would I form the following SQL query in RoR?

In SQL I would do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Gifts G
JOIN Payments P ON P.id = G.payment_id
JOIN Users    U ON U.id = P.user_id
WHERE G.type = 0
```

I have three models - Users, Payments and Gifts.

The schemas look like this:

```
Users has many Payments
Payments has many Gifts

Users

# Table name: users
# id      :integer          not null, primary key
# name    :string

Payments

# Table name: payments
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id     :integer
#  status      :integer

Gifts

# Table name: gifts
#
#  id         :integer              not null, primary key
#  payment_id :integer
#  name       :string
#  type       :integer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to define the associations between models,

Users
has_many :users

Payments
belongs_to :user
has_many :gifts

Gifts
belongs_to: payment

Now that you have the associations built up, you could use some AR (Active Record) to retrive the data. Thanks to rails you could use eager loding "mechanism for loading the associated records of the objects returned by Model". Here is where the magic begins.

Lest think you need to find from a user all they gifts.First you need to related to their payments and finally you can acces they gifts.All this using eager loading.
user = User.find(1)
user_gifts = user.payments.gifts

I havent tested the code yet but I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Jorge, I'm going to give this a try, after studying the has_many and belongs_to in detail.

Answer (score 1):

have you used the has_many keyword in your model? you can set up the model with active record to directly do the join for you!

Comment: Thanks Ben, but Jorge answered first and has given me enough direction to work it out, after some studying and testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Gifts.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM Gifts G
                  JOIN Payments P ON P.id = G.payment_id
                  JOIN Users    U ON U.id = P.user_id
                  WHERE G.type = 0")
```

And for ActiveRecord it could help. [Check it out](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables).

Comment: Good to know I can do this, but I think I'm going to try a more AR approach first.  Thanks.